maven plugin dependency-check with ApiKey
I'm using maven plugin dependency-check-maven version 10.0.4.
I also issued an ApiKey in order to download the database NVD quickly from web site: https://nvd.nist.gov/developers/request-an-api-key
In my dependency-check-maven configuration I set my key
<groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
<artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
<version>10.0.4</version>               
<configuration>
   <nvdApiKey>aa23a34b-xxxx-xxxx-9508-7bc89ba64772</nvdApiKey>
   <failBuildOnCVSS>7</failBuildOnCVSS>
   <assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>false</assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>
</configuration>
[...]

Anyway, when i execute mave command line
mvn dependency-check:check

[INFO] Checking for updates
[ERROR] Error updating the NVD Data
org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.update.exception.UpdateException: Error updating the NVD Data
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.update.NvdApiDataSource.processApi (NvdApiDataSource.java:395)
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.update.NvdApiDataSource.update (NvdApiDataSource.java:116)
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.Engine.doUpdates (Engine.java:906)
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.Engine.initializeAndUpdateDatabase (Engine.java:711)
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.Engine.analyzeDependencies (Engine.java:637)
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.maven.BaseDependencyCheckMojo.runCheck (BaseDependencyCheckMojo.java:1967)
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.maven.BaseDependencyCheckMojo.execute (BaseDependencyCheckMojo.java:1150)
[...]
Caused by: io.github.jeremylong.openvulnerability.client.nvd.NvdApiException: Invalid API Key: aa23a-*-64772

I'm sure of the value of the API Key as I received an email with this value.
Now I have also issued a new ApiKey but the results is the same also using the new key
Could you please help to understand the problem?
Thanks in advance

Couple of things to double check

There is no diff in the key received and the one used in the pom.xml

Ensure the key was activated. Because as per the email from NVD (see below), if you don't activate in seven days you lose it and need to raise new one. So make sure you clicked on the link like this https://nvd.nist.gov/developers/confirm-api-key?uuid=<someUnique value here>
Thank you for your request for an NVD API Key. Please click the link below to confirm your receipt of this email and activate your API Key. If your key is not activated within seven days, a request for a new API Key must be submitted.


